# Extract unquoted text from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string that may contain random segments of quoted and unquoted texts. For example,

`s = "\"java jobs in delhi\" it software \"pune\" hello"`.

I want to separate out the quoted and unquoted parts of this string in python.

So, basically I expect the output to be:

```
quoted_string = "\"java jobs in delhi\"" "\"pune\""
unquoted_string = "it software hello"
```

I believe using a regex is the best way to do it. But I am not very good with regex. Is there some regex expression that can help me with this?
Or is there a better solution available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your quotes are as basic as in your example, you could just split; example:

```
for s in (
    '"java jobs in delhi" it software "pune" hello',
    'foo "bar"',
):
    result = s.split('"')
    print 'text between quotes: %s' % (result[1::2],)
    print 'text outside quotes: %s' % (result[::2],)
```

Otherwise you could try:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(
    r'(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(?P<quote>["\'])(?P<value>.*?)(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(?P=quote)'
)

for s in data:
    print pattern.findall(s)
```

I explain the regex (I use it in [ihih](https://github.com/romain-dartigues/python-ihih/blob/master/ihih.py)):

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*           # find backslash
(?P<quote>["\'])           # any quote character (either " or ')
                           # which is *not* escaped (by a backslash)
(?P<value>.*?)             # text between the quotes
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(?P=quote) # end (matching) quote
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/B1gHTamNriCxHZ1t)
/
[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ENBCKz/1)

Answer (score 3):

I dislike regex for something like this, why not just use a split like this?

```
s = "\"java jobs in delhi\" it software \"pune\" hello"

print s.split("\"")[0::2] # Unquoted
print s.split("\"")[1::2] # Quoted
```

Comment: What if the string has 3+ parts of quoted text?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are hinting at @MarounMaroun ?

Comment: My mistake, sorry. First I though the code works only when you have two quoted strings, then I realized that that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex for that:

```
re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', s)
```

will return

```
['java jobs in delhi', 'pune']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Python's shlex module, it's very nice:

```
>>> from shlex import shlex
>>> def get_quoted_unquoted(s):
...     lexer = shlex(s)
...     items = list(iter(lexer.get_token, ''))
...     return ([i for i in items if i[0] in "\"'"],
                [i for i in items if i[0] not in "\"'"])
... 
>>> get_quoted_unquoted("\"java jobs in delhi\" it software \"pune\" hello")
(['"java jobs in delhi"', '"pune"'], ['it', 'software', 'hello'])
>>> get_quoted_unquoted("hello 'world' \"foo 'bar' baz\" hi")
(["'world'", '"foo \'bar\' baz"'], ['hello', 'hi'])
>>> get_quoted_unquoted("does 'nested \"quotes\" work' yes")
(['\'nested "quotes" work\''], ['does', 'yes'])
>>> get_quoted_unquoted("what's up with single quotes?")
([], ["what's", 'up', 'with', 'single', 'quotes', '?'])
>>> get_quoted_unquoted("what's up when there's two single quotes")
([], ["what's", 'up', 'when', "there's", 'two', 'single', 'quotes'])
```

I think this solution is as simple as any other solution (basically a oneliner, if you remove the function declaration and grouping) and it handles nested quotes well etc.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. It's one line. The module is built for this and the OP wanted to not only find quoted, but also unquoted strings.

Comment: Updated my answer with better examples of why I think shlex is a good choice.